# Python - how to replace string in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The script I'm writing generates a list called "trt" full of strings. Some of those strings may need to be replaced before the list is processed further. For instance, string "5" needs to be replaced with "4", but without messing with strings such as "-5" or "5*". The solution must not change the order of strings in the list "trt" or enter any new character or blank space in the list.

I've already tried to do it like this:

```
trt = [word.replace('5','4') for word in trt]
```

but it is not a good solution, as it affects "5*" and makes the script misbehave.

Comment: You need to use regex. See [`re module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: *and makes the script misbehave*. Define 'misbehave'?

Comment: Can you provide us with sample input and expected output?

Comment: @RohitJain He doesn't need regex, he's replacing strings in a list, not substrings in a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want this:

```
trt = ['4' if word == '5' else word for word in trt]
```

If you need to do a lot of these replacements, you might want to define a map:

```
replacements = {
    '5': '4',
    'a': 'b',
}
trt = [replacements.get(word, word) for word in trt]
```

`get` looks up `word` in the `replacements` dict and returns `word` itself if it doesn't find such a key, or the corresponding value if it does.

Comment: You, sir, are full of win.

Answer (score 1):

`word.replace('5','4')` replaces each 5 in the string word with a 4. This is not what you want to do (I don't think).

One solution:

```
for index, value in enumerate(trt):
    if value == "5":
        trt[index] = "4"
```

A more functional solution:

```
 trt = [i if i != "5" else "4" for i in trt]
```

Comment: the first solution makes more sense haha

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line lambda:

```
newlst = list(map(lambda x: '4' if x in ['5'] else x,lst))
```

Assume this is your list:

```
lst = ['-5','5*','5','-5','5']
```

Then:

```
newlst = list(map(lambda x: '4' if x in ['5'] else x,lst))
```

Returns:

```
['-5', '5*', '4', '-5', '4']
```